# Sinatra controller delete method failing

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I have a vendor model and controller where I've implemented the below delete method. Whenever I click the delete button, I get the "doesn't know this ditty" error.

```
  delete '/vendors/:id/delete' do
    @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])
    if logged_in? && @vendor.wedding.user == current_user
      @vendor.destroy
      redirect '/vendors'
    else
      redirect "/login", locals: {message: "Please log in to see that."}
    end
  end
```

My delete button:

```
<form action="/vendors/<%=@vendor.id%>/delete" method="post">
  <input id="hidden" type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
  <input type="submit" value="Delete Vendor">
</form>
```

My config.ru file already has 'use Rack::MethodOverride' and my edit/put forms are working fine so MethodOverride seems to be working.

Any idea why Sinatra is giving me the "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty" message just for deleting?

Comment: What style of app are you using, classic or modular (and if modular, subclassing `Base` or `Application`)? `method_override` isn’t always enabled, you might need to call `enable :method_override`.

Comment: Using modular style subclassing Base. Setting method_override in the controller did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214790/matt) in the comments, you might want to try enabling the method override in your app via `set`. For example, using the modular Sinatra setup:

```
class Application < Base

  set :method_override, true

  # routes here
end
```

There's a nice example [in this writeup](https://github.com/zhengjia/sinatra-explained/blob/master/app/tutorial_2/tutorial_2.md) as well